# Incorrect instanced rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

Previously, to render a bunch of quads, I was simply using a few uniforms (One for a model matrix and another for the texture layer ID), however, I'd rather not have to loop through each quad and set both uniforms each time, each frame.

So I went ahead and looked for better alternatives with which I could render everything with a single call.

Now I'm using instanced rendering:

```
// In VAO definition            
glGenBuffers(1, &instanceVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(RenderingData), nullptr);
glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(RenderingData), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(glm::vec4)));
glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(RenderingData), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(glm::vec4) * 2));
glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);
glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(RenderingData), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(glm::vec4) * 3));
glVertexAttribDivisor(6, 1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(7);
glVertexAttribIPointer(7, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, sizeof(RenderingData), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(glm::mat4)));
glVertexAttribDivisor(7, 1);

// In quad adding function
instanceData.push_back(quad->data);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(RenderingData) * quads.size(), &instanceData[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

// Rendering
glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, quads.size());
```

I'm using 2 VBOs: one for per-vertex data (Position, normal, etc vectors) and another for per-instance data (Model matrix and texture layer ID).

My problem is the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRKcv.jpg

As you can see, the middle and bottom images aren't rendering correctly (Middle one is way too stretched, whereas bottom one's UV are incorrect, since they aren't filling the whole quad), however, I'm 98% sure both my vertex and instance data are correct, since when I was using the previously mentioned uniforms, they were rendering correctly.

Also, I ***might*** 've spotted the problem: the indices. Somehow, if I change my glDrawElementsInstanced's count value to say, 12 indices, the middle one renders correctly, whereas the other 2, do not (Proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DfQE.jpg), same thing happens if I change them to 18 (The last one renders correctly and the other 2, do not).

What might the problem be?